# Proving supermartingale (sequence of uniformly distributed random variables)

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let's take $X_1 \sim U[0,1]$ and if $X_{n-1}=a$ then $X_n \sim U[0,a]$. I want t prove that $X_n$ is supermartingale.

So what I want to do prove is :

$$E[X_{n+1}\mid \mathbb{F}_n]\le X_n$$

And I have several problems with it. Let's just think a little about next expectations  :

$E[X_1]=\frac12$

$E[X_2]=\frac{a_1}{2}$

$E[X_3]=\frac{a_2}{2}$

and so on. So how can I translate it now to language of conditional expectation with filtration ? Is it really submartingale ? I found it very unintuitive.

Comment: Don't you want to prove the opposite inequality?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question!

Comment: Also,  what you wrote is somewhat confusing (what is $a_i$?), but I think what you mean is $E[X_{i+1}\mid F_i] = \frac{1}{2}X_i,$ from which the inequality is immediate.

Comment: so why exactly $E[X_{i+1}|F_i ]\le \frac12 X_i$ ? It's so obvious for me

Comment: It's not that $E[X_{i+1}\mid F_i]\le \frac{1}{2}X_i.$ It's that $E[X_{i+1}\mid F_i]= \frac{1}{2}X_i\le X_i.$

Comment: Like your intuition that led you to write down $E[X_{i+1}]=\frac{a_i}{2}$ (which is formally meaningless as written since what is $a_i$?) is really your intuition telling you that  $E[X_{i+1}\mid F_i]= \frac{1}{2}X_i.$

Comment: You might also note that $(X_n)$ is   a *decreasing* sequence with values in $[0,1]$, hence a supermartingale.